# Как открыть сайт по протоколу http в Firefox"?

Tags: http, https, firefox

Есть сайт, который нужно открывать только по http. При вводе в адресную строку соответствующий путь все равно оно пытается его открыть по https. Хром нормально открывает, но я люблю фф.
Режим only https отключен
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В **about:config** для насйтроки browser.urlbar.autoFill тоже установлено false
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какие настройки я мог упустить? Подскажите, пожалуйста, как все-таки заставить ff открывать сайт по http?

Comment: Почистить кэш, убедиться в отсутствии HSTS?

Comment: а приставку `http://` вручную перед урл адресом прописывали ?

Comment: В большинстве своём сайты делают редирект с http на https. Скорее всего проблема заключается именно в этом. Хотя если в хроме этот сайт можно открыть по http, то проблема явно не в этом

Comment: @Zt.
Естественно. Оно автоматом на https кидает. Помогла очистка кеша после того как сменил настройки